# Remove () method in Linked List to remove lowest score

Tags: java, linked-list

I want the GameEntry Score to remove the lowest score after add into GameEntry if with the high score.
I set maximum entry is 10. if more than 10 it should remove the lowest score and replace the index.
i try to use remove() method to show in main.
Here i am using Single Linked List. Please help to review and feedback where i missed.Thanks.

```
public class ScoresSingleLL {

private GameEntry head; //head node to hold the list

    //It Contains a static inner class Game Entry
    private static class GameEntry{
        private int score;
        private GameEntry next;
        
        public GameEntry(int score) {
            this.score = score;
            this.next = null;
        }
        
        public int getScore() {
        return score;
        }

    }
    
    private static final int highestScoregames = 10;
    private int totalAdded = 0;
    private GameEntry[] games = new GameEntry[highestScoregames];
    
    
    public void add(GameEntry game) {
        game.next = head;
        head = game;
        int score = game.getScore();
        if (totalAdded == highestScoregames) {
        if (score <= games[totalAdded - 1].getScore()) {
        return;
        }
        } else {
        totalAdded++;
        }

        int i = totalAdded - 1;
        for (; (i >= 1) &&(score > games[i -1].getScore()); i--) {
        games[i] =games[i - 1];
        }
        games[i] = game;
        
        }
    
    public void remove(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

        GameEntry game = head;
        games[i] = game;
        
        if ((i < 0) || (i >= totalAdded)) { //i is score where less than total added score
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + i);
        }
                
        
        for (int j = i; j < totalAdded -1; j++) {
        games[j] = games[j + 1];
        }

        games[totalAdded - 1] = null;
        totalAdded--;
            
        }

    
    
        
    public void display() {

        GameEntry current = head;
        while(current != null){
            System.out.print("Game Entry [Score = "+ current.score +"]" + "  ");
            current = current.next;             
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        
        GameEntry game1 = new GameEntry(1);
        GameEntry game2 = new GameEntry(2);
        GameEntry game3 = new GameEntry(3);
        GameEntry game4 = new GameEntry(4);
        GameEntry game5 = new GameEntry(5);
        GameEntry game6 = new GameEntry(6);
        GameEntry game7 = new GameEntry(7);
        GameEntry game8 = new GameEntry(8);
        GameEntry game9 = new GameEntry(9);
        GameEntry game10 = new GameEntry(10);
        GameEntry game11 = new GameEntry(11);
        
        ScoresSingleLL scores = new ScoresSingleLL();
        
        scores.add(game1);
        scores.add(game2);
        scores.add(game3);
        scores.add(game4);
        scores.add(game5);
        scores.add(game6);
        scores.add(game7);
        scores.add(game8);
        scores.add(game9);
        scores.add(game10); 
        
        scores.display();   
        scores.add(game11);
        scores.remove(0);
        scores.display();
        

    }

}
```

Comment: You are maintaining the list both as an array and as a linked list. Why?

Comment: @trincot actually i convert it from array list to linked List. so yeah i just try ou the method to get same output.

Comment: Ok. There are answers below. Could you give feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is maintaining the objects as linked list *and* as array. This is overkill. There are several instances in your code where you do not keep them in sync. You should go for one of these data structures only.

As your question is about linked list, I suggest to drop the array. You also don't need `totalAdded`.

Here is the corrected code for the two functions. The `add` function will also ensure that the list will not get too long. It will remove item(s) at the end when that happens:

```
    private static final int highestScoregames = 10;
    
    public void add(GameEntry game) {
        if (highestScoregames == 0) { // Nothing allowed
             head = null;
             return;
        }
        if (head == null) {
            head = game;
            return;
        }
        int score = game.getScore();
        int count = 1;
        GameEntry current = head;
        if (score >= head.getScore()) {
            game.next = head;
            current = head = game;
        } else {
            while (current.next != null && current.next.getScore() > score) {
                current = current.next;
                count++;
            }
            // Insert game here
            game.next = current.next;
            current.next = game;
        }
        while (current.next != null && count < highestScoregames) {
            current = current.next;
            count++;
        }
        // Clip the rest of the list
        current.next = null;
    }
    
    public void remove(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (i < 0 || head == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + i);
        } 
        if (i == 0) {
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        GameEntry game = head;
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            game = game.next;
            if (game == null || game.next == null) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + i);
            }
        }
        // Remove game.next
        game.next = game.next.next;
    }
```

Comment: i see..noted..i will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: i have Dead code for this:
 if (highestScoregames == 0) { // Nothing allowed
             head = null;
             return;
        }

Comment: Yes, but it is there in case you would ever set `highestScoregames` to 0 in its declaration. If you never intend to do that, you can remove that part of the code.

Comment: Thanks. my next code need redo this output in Double linked List and Circular Linked List. will try my best to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The below code - Adds new GameEntry towards the end until total entries are less than 10.
Removes GameEntry at the given index.
Once total GameEntry reaches 10, the next GameEntry to be added is inserted at the existing GameEntry with the minimum score.

```
public class ScoresSingleLL {
    private GameEntry head;
    private int size;

    private static class GameEntry {
        private int score;
        private GameEntry next;

        GameEntry(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "GameEntry{" +
                    "score=" + score +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    /**
     * 1. Adds new GameEntry
     * 2. If size exceeds 10 then replace GameEntry with min score with the new GameEntry
     */
    public void add(GameEntry gameEntry) {
        if(size == 10) {

            // 1. Find the GameEntry with min score  and its index
            // 2. Call remove(index) to remove GameEntry at index from #1
            // 3. Call add(gameEntry, index) to replace a new GameEntry at index from #1
            GameEntry current = head;
            int min = current.score;
            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                current = current.next;
                if(current.score < min) {
                    min = current.score;
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            remove(index);
            add(gameEntry, index);
            return;
        }

        // Adds new GameEntry by appending towards the end

        if(head == null) {
            head = gameEntry;
            head.next = null;

        } else {
            GameEntry current = head;
            while(current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = gameEntry;
            gameEntry.next = null;
        }
        size++;
    }

    /**
     Called only when removing GameEntry with min score and replace it with new GameEntry
     */
    private void add(GameEntry gameEntry, int index) {
        if(index < 0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Index : " + index);
        }
        if(index == 0) {
            gameEntry.next = head;
            head = gameEntry;
            size++;
            return;
        }

        GameEntry current = head;
        GameEntry previous = null;

        for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        previous.next = gameEntry;
        gameEntry.next = current;
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Remove GameEntry at the given index
     */
    public void remove(int index) {
        if(size == 0 || index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + index);
        }

        if(index == 0) {
            head = head.next;
            size--;
            return;
        }

        GameEntry current = head;
        GameEntry previous = null;

        for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = current.next;
        size--;
    }

    /**
     * Print all present GameEntry
     */
    public void display() {
        if(head == null) {
            System.out.println("No GameEntry Present");
            return;
        }

        GameEntry current = head;
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.println(current);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScoresSingleLL scoresList = new ScoresSingleLL();
        System.out.println("\n-------- GameEntry at the beginning --------");
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Adding 10 GameEntry --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(1));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(2));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(3));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(3));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(4));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(6));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(7));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(8));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(9));
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(-2));
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(10) in place of min score = -2 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(10));
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(11) in place of min score = 1 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(11));
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(13) in place of min score = 2 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(13));
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(14) in place of 1st occurrence of min score = 3 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(14)); // Add in place of 1st occurrence of min = 3
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(5) in place of min score = 3 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(5)); // Add in place of min = 3
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Remove GameEntry at 5th index i.e. score 6 --------");
        scoresList.remove(5); // Removes element at 5th index i.e. score 6
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(15) towards the end --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(15)); // Add new entry towards the end
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Add GameEntry(16) in place of min score = 4 --------");
        scoresList.add(new GameEntry(16)); // Add in place of min = 4
        scoresList.display();

        System.out.println("\n-------- Remove all GameEntry one by one --------");
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.remove(0);
        scoresList.display();
    }

}
```

Output

```
-------- GameEntry at the beginning --------
No GameEntry Present

-------- Adding 10 GameEntry --------
GameEntry{score=1}
GameEntry{score=2}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=-2}

-------- Add GameEntry(10) in place of min score = -2 --------
GameEntry{score=1}
GameEntry{score=2}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Add GameEntry(11) in place of min score = 1 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=2}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Add GameEntry(13) in place of min score = 2 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Add GameEntry(14) in place of 1st occurrence of min score = 3 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=14}
GameEntry{score=3}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Add GameEntry(5) in place of min score = 3 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=14}
GameEntry{score=5}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=6}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Remove GameEntry at 5th index i.e. score 6 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=14}
GameEntry{score=5}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}

-------- Add GameEntry(15) towards the end --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=14}
GameEntry{score=5}
GameEntry{score=4}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}
GameEntry{score=15}

-------- Add GameEntry(16) in place of min score = 4 --------
GameEntry{score=11}
GameEntry{score=13}
GameEntry{score=14}
GameEntry{score=5}
GameEntry{score=16}
GameEntry{score=7}
GameEntry{score=8}
GameEntry{score=9}
GameEntry{score=10}
GameEntry{score=15}

-------- Remove all GameEntry one by one --------
No GameEntry Present
```